# Is it okay to run the software updater frequently?

Tags: 14.04, updates

I’m asking this because I’m just scared in case it installs a unstable version of something (like Firefox or steam etc...) then either the application wont work or my boot order changes serverly (yeah its happened before ;-;)
thanks!

Comment: ...then don't run it frequently.

Comment: @mikewhatever seems legit

Comment: Unless you've explicitly enabled some repository which provides an unstable Firefox, you won't get an unstable Firefox. You will only get normal and security updates of Firefox by default. As for Steam, it updates itself entirely outside the realm of package management. If you don't want unstable Steam, then don't sign up to the Steam beta updates program within Steam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't depend on frequency of update, rather it depends of how you choose to update. Unless, you tick pre-released (proposed)  and unsupported (backports) updates, you are probably not going to have unstable software.

[image]

See here for more info: [Ubuntu updates wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuUpdates)